# What method should I use to store collections of data locally using React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react native app that stores data on your day, like a diary.

Here, each day, you would store data on:

- A title
- A description
- A collection of people you spent it with
- Google maps location of where you were
- And a overall rating (bad, okay or great)

I assumed I would store this in some sort of class somewhere, however looking into React and experimenting with AsyncStorage it seems you can only store data one at a time and it must be a string.

My question is what would be the best method to store data as a collection like this? Should I stringify it? Or is there another method to store data like this not using AsyncStorage?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There many method can can used on react native to saving / persisting data, if you only store small data, using AsyncStorage is fit for your case. But if you need storing structured data and large amount, i recommend using:

- Redux Persist [Github Link](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)
- Sqlite storage [Github Link](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)
- Realm js [Github Link](https://github.com/realm/realm-js)
- Watermelon DB [Github Link](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)
- and much more

Comment: I should have been more clear, in the app you would be storing data on multiple days with each day containing data on each of those categories.

Would Async fit this? I have tried using it but it doesn't seem to fit what I need at all but perhaps I am just misunderstanding it

Comment: storing data using AsyncStorage is good for your case, if you need more control about your data you should run that logic before save it. Example, if you need previous data saved and merge with new data you just control on javascript side not in AsyncStorage. AsyncStorage is key value data store, so you need extra code to manage your data, if you need storing data to column based data store you can using sqlite storage its same as you manage data on server side

Comment: I have attempted to store JSON objects with AsyncStorage but it wouldn't work, I assumed this was because the key/data couldn't use JSON objects and instead had to be a string. Is this the case? 

If so, is it possible to store collections of data (like a class instantiation) with AsyncStorage?

Comment: yes you should make object data to string (`JSON.stringify`) before save it. Class instantiation only works on javascript side, if you convert that class to string, that class getter / setter will not working after deserialization, setter / getter is only available on memory and can't be saved to storage

Comment: Okay awesome, thanks a lot! I'll give stringify a shot!